# Server doest response to client through ssl

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx

I have web app with react and node.js that I deploted to server, in my server nginx is running, and I added SSL.

I can access the front from my broswer using https, but when i try to connect with the server from my app, i get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

this is my nginx site-enables relvavnt fields:

```
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{my-app-domain}/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{my-app-domain}/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

```
      server_name www.my-app-url my-app-url; # managed by Certbot
      location / {
              proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      }

      location /api {
              proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
      }
```

the request that failed looks like this:

```
 https://{serverIp}:5000/api/users/register
```

Comment: Your nginx isn't listening on 5000, and it can't since your backend is already using that port. Your nginx is listening on 443, so you need to connect to `https://server:443/` or just `https://server` since 443 is the default per standard. And you not only can use the domainname (as hedgeho says), for most clients you MUST do so because clients are supposed to match the URL to the name(s) in the cert (some don't) and a cert frome LE (or most other CAs) only contains your domainname(s) not your IPaddress(es).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `proxy_pass`, you don't have to access the server via `{serverIp}:5000`, you can use your domain instead.

If that doesn't fix the problem, I suggest looking into nginx logs:
`nano /var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: But :5000 only accesses one of backends, not nginx, so nginx will not have logged anything.

Comment: thanks also @dave_thompson_085 your explanation was helpfull also